# SKLableNode - using image as color pattern

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit

I want to create a label node using gradient. 
There is a way to do it outside of sprite kit, with UILabel for example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

...but its not working with label nodes (text becomes invisible, no errors tho).
I also tried using SKColor instead of UIColor.

Any idea why its not working? Or if there is a different way to achieve gradient text in sprite kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprite Kit doesn't do pattern colors. You can, however, use a label node to mask out an area of another sprite's image using SKCropNode.